# Сокрытие реального источника видео

Tags: django, http, видео, blob, privacy

Как максимально скрыть реальный источник видео?

1) Ложный источник (вроде django/php скрипта) запрашивает с настоящего источника видео, отдаёт http response с нужными заголовками и телом. Проблема: видео не появится до полной его загрузки, как же динамическая загрузка?

2) Не помогают ли blob ссылки?

3) Настройка nginx/apache?

4) Что-то вроде известного уже готового прокси сервера, который выполняет работу скриптов из 1-го варианта?

5) Ещё какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: Для динамической загрузки должен подойти [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects). Тем не менее django не заточена на такие извращение, и лучше вообще освободить джангу от любых манипуляций с видео

Comment: Настроить apache/nginx под задачу?

Comment: @JediKnight почему именно apache/ngnix ? Можно заставить джангу управлять потоками на каком нибудь icecast с припасёнными заранее слотами трансляции. Слоты сами способны сообщать стороннему серверу о подключении / отключении юзера и брать заданные файлы. Django останется только подсовывать свободным слотам нужные видео.

Comment: Я реализовывал например авторизацию на icecast через django с токеном спрятанным в http-user-agent. Даёте юзеру на его клиенте ссыль на слот с потоком, который запускается при подключении и авторизации по токену из агента. Вуаля.

Comment: По отключению высвобождаете слот.

Comment: Пытался следовать этому руководству (https://linuxolyk.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/video-live-streaming-part-2-icecast/), даже не получилось настримить свой экран. Плохо представляю, как он будет брать видео с другого сайта.

Comment: @JediKnight в базовом руководстве icecast достаточно подробной информации, чтобы ее запустить и настроить. Из подсказок: Вам необходимо использовать параметры <authentication type="url">. В них пропишете url к своему серверу. Будете получать сигналы через них о начале и конце стриминга по каждому слоту в своем бэкэнде, и в нём же формировать / высвобождать слоты.

Comment: А для корректного воспроизведения у юзера используйте <intro> на статик файлы, которые будут иметь ссылки на реальные необходимые к вещанию. Естественно, ссылки нужно будет менять при запуске / высвобождению слотов. А если хотите дополнительной защиты - передайте клиенту токен, который он должен зафигачить useragetnt. В этом случае на бэкэнде вы сможете сравнивать выданый токен с тем что прислал icecast по auth событию,  и отсекать негодяев если они появятся.

Comment: Без бизнес логики такой бэкэнд пишется за полдня вместе с отладкой :)